# Prove Graph is connected

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every graph $G= (V, E)$ where $\forall$ v $\in$ V, $d(v) \ge |V|- 3$
and $|V| > 4$ is connected.

I was able to prove that this graph would be cyclic as well as 
$|E| \ge \frac{n^2-3}{2}$

But how do i prove that the graph must be connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x, y$ be two arbitrary, distinct vertices of $G$. If they aren't neighbours, then they each have $|V|-3$ neighbours in the remaining $|V|-2$ vertices. If $|V|>4$, that necessarily means that they have a neighbour in common (since $2(|V|-3) > |V|-2$, so the two sets of size $|V|-3$ necessarily have some overlap), and the two vertices are therefore connected by a path of length at most $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the graph has two connected components $H,K$. So there exists vertices $x \ \in V(H)$ and $y \in V(K)$. Now as $\text{deg}(x) \ge |V| - 3$ we have that $|V(H)| \ge |V| - 2$ ($x$ and the neighbors of $x$ are in $H$). Similarly $|V(K)| \ge |V| - 2$. But now as the vertex sets are disjoint you have:

$$|V| \ge |V(H)| + |V(K)| \ge |V| - 2 + |V| - 2 \iff 4 \ge |V|$$

From this you obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Write $n=|V|$. Every vertex has at least $n-3$ neighbors, i.e. every connected component is at least of size $n-2$. If you have two such components of size $a$ and $b$, we have

$$n=a+b\ge n-2+n-2=2n-4\quad\implies\quad n\le 4.$$

Similar for more components.